# separate dev and prod crashlitics reports

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I created two database on firebase (Prod and Dev environment).
I linked the first crashlitics with my app. I would like to link my second database too. It doesn't work, dev environment crashlitics does not recognize my app when i build and launch. 
Firstly is it possible ?

Comment: Have you got one or two `google-services.json` files?

Comment: i have two google-services.json

Comment: I separated them on my android studio project, in a release and debug folder.
It works for firebase database.